# haskell list comprehension performance

Tags: performance, haskell, list-comprehension

Below are three versions of brute-force Pythagorean triplets problem with an additional constraint that a+b+c=1000. All of them were complied with -O3 with GHC 7.0.3. Sample run-times are listed below.

**Questions**:

1. Why does the second version run faster then the first?
2. Why does the third version run faster than the second?

I realize that the difference is small, but the ordering is consistent on average.

```
main=print . product . head $ [[a,b,c] | a<-[1..1000],b<-[a..1000], let c=1000-a-b, a^2+b^2==c^2]
real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.039s
sys     0m0.005s

main=print . product . head $ [[a,b,c] | a<-[1..1000],b<-[1..1000], let c=1000-a-b, a^2+b^2==c^2]
real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.006s

main=print . product . head $ [[a,b,c] | a<-[1..1000],b<-[1..1000], b>=a, let c=1000-a-b, a^2+b^2==c^2]
real    0m0.040s
user    0m0.033s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Comment: Are the first and second not exactly the same?

Comment: @monadic: they differ: `b<-[a..1000]` vs `b<-[1..1000]`

Comment: @Raeez Ah, okay, thanks. Wasn't on my linux box so I couldn't run diff like I normally do to figure out what the difference is :)

Comment: The difference between the first and the second versions looks too small to distinguish from measurement error.  The same possibly applies to the third one, too.

Comment: Don't use -O3. GHC only has optimization levels up to two. I don't know what happens if you go above that these days but it used to be the case that higher values gave worse code. -O should be enough, -O2 enables one or two additional optimization on top of that but for many programs doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @monadic: haha, I had to run a cmp to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's name the three programs **A**, **B** and **C** respectively.

### **C** vs **B**

We'll begin with the simplest: **C** has an extra constraint (`b >= a`) relative to **B**. Intuitively, this means that the search space traversed in **C** is smaller than that of **B**. We can rationalize this by noting that instead of ranging over every possibly permuted pair `a, b` (of which we know there are `1000^2=1000000` possible pairs)  we instead do not consider all those cases where `b` is smaller than `a`. Presumably, the check for whether or not `b >= a` produces a little bit of extra code (the comparison) that is outweighed by computation avoided by running the comparison, hence we note a (slight) speed-up. Fair enough.

### **B** vs **A**

The next is a bit trickier: It appears that **A** has the same constraint as **C** (`b >= a`), but encoded differently (i.e. here we have it encoded as the range of values `b` may attain in the `List Monad`). We might think then that **A** should run faster than **B** (as indeed, it should run similarly to **C**). Clearly then, our intuition is lacking.

### To the Core

Now, since we can't always trust our intuition we should investigate what's *really* going on in the generated [GHC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core). Lets dump the core for our 3 programs (sans optimizations):

```
for p in A B C
do
  ghc -ddump-simpl $p.hs >> $p.core
done
```

If we compare `B.core` and `C.core`, we'll note that both files have roughly the same structure:

Begin by calling a few familiar functions `(System.IO.print ...)`, `(Data.List.product ...)` and `(GHC.List.head ...)`

Next, we define a pair of nested recursive functions with signature:

```
ds_dxd [Occ=LoopBreaker]
    :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer] -> [[GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]]
```

We call each of these defined functions on an enumeration of the form:

```
    (GHC.Enum.enumFromTo                
    @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer       
    GHC.Num.$fEnumInteger            
    (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 1)     
    (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 1000)))
```

and perform our logic within the innermost defined function. Of note, we can see that in `B.core` we see

```
                     case GHC.Classes.==
                            @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
                            ...
                            (GHC.Num.+
                               ...
                               (GHC.Real.^
                                  ...
                                  ds3_dxc
                                  (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 2))
                               (GHC.Real.^
                                  ...
                                  ds8_dxg
                                  (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 2)))
                            (GHC.Real.^
                               ...
                               c_abw
                               (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 2))
```

corresponding to a naive filter of all the possible values conforming to our constraint, whereas in `C.core`, we instead have:

```
case GHC.Classes.>=
    @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer GHC.Classes.$fOrdInteger ds8_dxj ds3_dxf
    of _ {
        GHC.Bool.False -> ds5_dxh ds9_dxk;
        GHC.Bool.True ->
        let {
        ...
                case GHC.Classes.==
                ...
```

corresponding to the addition of an extra `>=` constraint before our triplet constraint, and hence searching through fewer integers for a shorter runtime, just as our intuition expects.

In comparing `A.core` and `B.core`, we immediately see a familiar structure (a nested pair of recursive functions each called over an enumeration) and in-fact, it appears that the core output for `A` and `B` are nearly identical! The difference, it seems, lies in the innermost enumeration:

```
            ds5_dxd
             (GHC.Enum.enumFromTo
                @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
                GHC.Num.$fEnumInteger
                ds3_dxb
                (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 1000))
```

where we see the enumeration range from a given induction variable `ds3_dxb` to `1000`, as opposed to remaining as a static range (`[1..1000`]).

What gives then? Should this not indicate that **A** should run faster than **B**? (we naively expect **A** to perform similarly to **C**, given that they implement the same constraints). Well, it turns out that the various compiler optimizations in-play produce exceedingly complex behaviour, and the various combinations often yield non-intuitive (and frankly bizarre) results, and in this case, we have **two** compilers interplaying with one another: `ghc` and `gcc`. In order to have a chance at understanding these results, we have to rely on the generated *optimized core* (Ultimately though, it's the generated assembler that truly counts, but we'll ignore that for now).

### To the Optimized Core, and Beyond

Let's generate the optimized core:

```
for p in A B C
do
  ghc -O3 -ddump-simpl $p.hs >> $p.core
done
```

and compare our problem child(**A**) to its faster counterparts. Comparatively **B** and **C** both perform a class of optimizations that **A** alone cannot: *let-floating* and *lambda-lifting*. We can see this by noting that our recursive functions in **B** and **C** have some `40` fewer lines of code in them, resulting in tighter inner-loops. To understand why **A** is not benefiting from this optimization, we should take a look at the code that is not being floated out:

```
let {
  c1_s10T
    :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
       -> [[GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]]
       -> [[GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]]
  [LclId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType LL]
  c1_s10T =
    \ (ds2_dxg :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)
      (ds3_dxf :: [[GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]]) ->
      let {
        c2_s10Q [Dmd=Just L] :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
        [LclId, Str=DmdType]
        c2_s10Q = GHC.Integer.minusInteger lvl2_s10O ds2_dxg } in -- subtract
      case GHC.Integer.eqInteger
             (GHC.Integer.plusInteger lvl3_s10M (GHC.Real.^_^ ds2_dxg lvl_r11p))
             -- add two squares (lve3_s10M has been floated out)
             (GHC.Real.^_^ c2_s10Q lvl_r11p)
             -- ^ compared to this square
      of _ {
        GHC.Bool.False -> ds3_dxf;
        GHC.Bool.True ->
          GHC.Types.:
            @ [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
            (GHC.Types.:
               @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
               ds_dxe
               (GHC.Types.:
                  @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
                  ds2_dxg
                  (GHC.Types.:
                     @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
                     c2_s10Q
                     (GHC.Types.[] @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer))))
            ds3_dxf
      } } in
```

that is, a subtraction (`minusInteger`) and an equality (`eqInteger`) as well as two squares (`^_^`) are being performed within the critical section of our loop (represented by the body of a helper function), whereas the same helper function in `C.core` contains fewer computations (and if we dug further, we'd see that it's because GHC is unable to determine whether it is safe to float these calculations out in the optimization pass). This matches our earlier analysis head-on, as we can see that the constraint (`b >= a`) **is** indeed present, just unlike **C**, we have been unable to float the majority of the redundant calculation outside the loop.

To confirm, let's increase the bounds of the loop involved arbitrarily (for the sake of demonstration), say, to `[1..10000]`. We should expect to see that **A's** runtime behaviour should be asymptotically close to **C's** runtime behaviour, just as we expect **B** to be left in the dust.

```
➜  time ./A                                 
./A  0.37s user 0.01s system 74% cpu 0.502 total  
➜  time ./B                                 
./B  3.21s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 3.246 total  
➜  time ./C                                 
./C  0.33s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.343 total
```

and what do you know, it's just as we expect! Your initial bounds were simply too small for any interesting performance characteristics to shine through (whatever theory may tell you, constant overhead *does matter in practice*). Another way of looking at this result is that our initial intuition about **A** matching **C's** performance was actually more accurate then it first appeared.

Of course, all of this may be overkill for the code sample at hand, but this sort of analysis can be very useful in resource-constrained environments.

Comment: Thank you, Raeez, for such a detailed answer!