# How do I optimise this Haskell limit order book (with code, reports, graphs)?

Tags: haskell, optimization, functional-programming, compiler-optimization, computational-finance

I've written a haskell version of a limit order book, referencing this version written in C:

https://github.com/jordanbaucke/Limit-Order-Book/blob/master/Others/C%2B%2B/engine.c

A limit order book is the mechanism many stock and currency exchanges use for computing trades of currency and stock.

This haskell version (source code further down) submits 2000 random limit orders to the orderbook, and calculates the average execution price.

```
main = do
  orders <- randomOrders
  let (orderBook, events) = foldr (\order (book, ev) -> let (b, e) = processOrder order book in (b, ev++e)) (empty, []) 
                            (take 2000 orders) 
  let (total, count) = ((fromIntegral $ sum $ map executePrice events), fromIntegral $ length events)
  print $ "Average execution price: " ++ show (total / count) ++ ", " ++ (show count) ++ " executions"
```

I've compiled it with -O2, and running the program without profiling takes almost 10 seconds.

```
time ./main                                                           
"Average execution price: 15137.667036215817, 2706.0 executions"
./main  9.90s user 0.09s system 89% cpu 11.205 total
```

I've tried to set the program to process 10000 orders, taking 160 seconds.

```
time ./main
"Average execution price: 15047.099824996354, 13714.0 executions"
./main  161.99s user 2.08s system 57% cpu 4:44.16 total
```

What can I do to make it dramatically faster without sacrificing functionality? Do you think it is possible to bring it to process 10000 orders per second?

Here are the memory usage charts (with the 2000 orders), generated with +RTS hc/hd/hy and hp2ps:
[image: Memory usage charts]

Here is the source code:

```
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import Data.Word
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Tuple
import Debug.Trace
import System.Random
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

-- Price is measured in smallest divisible unit of currency.
type Price = Word64

maximumPrice = 30000

type Quantity = Word64
type Trader a = a
type Entry a = (Quantity, Trader a)
type PricePoint a = [Entry a]
data OrderBook a = OrderBook {
  pricePoints :: Array Price (PricePoint a),
  minAsk :: Price,
  maxBid :: Price
} deriving (Show)

data Side = Buy | Sell deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Enum, Bounded)

instance Random Side where
  randomR (a, b) g =
    case randomR (fromEnum a, fromEnum b) g of
      (x, g') -> (toEnum x, g')
  random g = randomR (minBound, maxBound) g

data Order a = Order {
  side :: Side,
  price :: Price,
  size :: Quantity,
  trader :: Trader a
} deriving (Show)


data Event a =
  Execution {
    buyer :: Trader a,
    seller :: Trader a,
    executePrice :: Price,
    executeQuantity :: Quantity
  } deriving (Show)


empty :: OrderBook a
empty = OrderBook {
  pricePoints = array (1, maximumPrice) [(i, []) | i <- [1..maximumPrice]],
  minAsk = maximumPrice,
  maxBid = 0
}

insertOrder :: Order a -> OrderBook a -> OrderBook a
insertOrder (Order side price size t) (OrderBook pricePoints minAsk maxBid) = 
  OrderBook {
    pricePoints = pricePoints // [(price, (pricePoints!price) ++ [(size, t)])],
    maxBid = if side == Buy  && maxBid < price then price else maxBid,
    minAsk = if side == Sell && minAsk > price then price else minAsk
  }

processOrder :: Order a -> OrderBook a -> (OrderBook a, [Event a])
processOrder order orderBook
  | size /= 0 && price `comp` current =
    let (_order, _ob, _events) = executeForPrice order{price=current} _orderBook
    in (\(a,b) c -> (a,c++b)) (processOrder _order{price=price} _ob) _events
  | otherwise = (insertOrder order orderBook, [])
  where
    Order side price size _ = order
    (current, comp, _orderBook) 
      | side == Buy  = (minAsk orderBook, (>=), orderBook{minAsk=current+1})
      | side == Sell = (maxBid orderBook, (<=), orderBook{maxBid=current-1})

executeForPrice :: Order a -> OrderBook a -> (Order a, OrderBook a, [Event a])
executeForPrice order orderBook
  | null pricePoint = (order, orderBook, [])
  | entrySize < size = (\(a, b, c) d -> (a, b, d:c))
    (executeForPrice order{size=size-entrySize} (set rest)) (execute entrySize)
  | otherwise =
    let entries
          | entrySize > size = (entrySize-size, entryTrader):rest
          | otherwise = rest 
    in (order{size=0}, set entries, [execute size])
  where
    pricePoint = (pricePoints orderBook)!price
    (entrySize, entryTrader):rest = pricePoint
    Order side price size trader = order
    set = \p -> orderBook{pricePoints=(pricePoints orderBook)//[(price, p)]}
    (buyer, seller) = (if side == Buy then id else swap) (trader, entryTrader)
    execute = Execution buyer seller price

randomTraders :: IO [Int]
randomTraders = do
  g <- newStdGen
  return (randomRs (1, 3) g)

randomPrices :: IO [Word64]
randomPrices = do
  g <- newStdGen
  return (map fromIntegral $ randomRs (1 :: Int, fromIntegral maximumPrice) g)

randomSizes :: IO [Word64]
randomSizes = do
  g <- newStdGen
  return (map fromIntegral $ randomRs (1 :: Int, 10) g)

randomSides :: IO [Side]
randomSides = do
  g <- newStdGen
  return (randomRs (Buy, Sell) g)

randomOrders = do
  sides <- randomSides
  prices <- randomPrices
  sizes <- randomSizes
  traders <- randomTraders
  let zipped = zip4 sides prices sizes traders
  let orders = map (\(side, price, size, trader) -> Order side price size trader) zipped
  return orders

main = do
  orders <- randomOrders
  let (orderBook, events) = foldr (\order (book, ev) -> let (b, e) = processOrder order book in (b, ev++e)) (empty, []) 
                            (take 2000 orders) 
  let (total, count) = ((fromIntegral $ sum $ map executePrice events), fromIntegral $ length events)
  print $ "Average execution price: " ++ show (total / count) ++ ", " ++ (show count) ++ " executions"
```

Here are the profiling reports:

```
ghc -rtsopts --make -O2 OrderBook.hs -o main -prof -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp
time ./main +RTS -sstderr +RTS -hd -p -K100M && hp2ps -e8in -c main.hp    
./main +RTS -sstderr -hd -p -K100M 
"Average execution price: 15110.97202536367, 2681.0 executions"
   3,184,295,808 bytes allocated in the heap
     338,666,300 bytes copied during GC
       5,017,560 bytes maximum residency (149 sample(s))
         196,620 bytes maximum slop
              14 MB total memory in use (2 MB lost due to fragmentation)

  Generation 0:  4876 collections,     0 parallel,  1.98s,  2.01s elapsed
  Generation 1:   149 collections,     0 parallel,  1.02s,  1.07s elapsed

  INIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT   time    5.16s  (  5.24s elapsed)
  GC    time    3.00s  (  3.08s elapsed)
  RP    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF  time    0.01s  (  0.01s elapsed)
  EXIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total time    8.17s  (  8.33s elapsed)

  %GC time      36.7%  (36.9% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    617,232,166 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  63.1% of total user, 61.9% of total elapsed

./main +RTS -sstderr +RTS -hd -p -K100M  8.17s user 0.06s system 98% cpu 8.349 total
cat main.prof
  Sun Feb  9 12:03 2014 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

     main +RTS -sstderr -hd -p -K100M -RTS

  total time  =        0.64 secs   (32 ticks @ 20 ms)
  total alloc = 1,655,532,980 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE                    MODULE               %time %alloc

processOrder                   Main                  46.9   81.2
insertOrder                    Main                  21.9    0.0
executeForPrice                Main                  18.8    9.7
randomPrices                   Main                   9.4    0.1
main                           Main                   3.1    4.5
minAsk                         Main                   0.0    2.1
maxBid                         Main                   0.0    2.0


                                                                                               individual    inherited
COST CENTRE              MODULE                                               no.    entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                     MAIN                                                   1           0   0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                    Main                                                 392           3   3.1    4.5   100.0   99.8
  executePrice           Main                                                 417        2681   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  processOrder           Main                                                 398     5695463  46.9   81.2    87.5   95.0
   executeForPrice       Main                                                 412     5695252  18.8    9.7    18.8    9.7
    pricePoints          Main                                                 413     5695252   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   insertOrder           Main                                                 406        1999  21.9    0.0    21.9    0.0
   minAsk                Main                                                 405           0   0.0    2.1     0.0    2.1
   maxBid                Main                                                 400           0   0.0    2.0     0.0    2.0
  randomOrders           Main                                                 393           1   0.0    0.0     9.4    0.2
   randomTraders         Main                                                 397           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   randomSizes           Main                                                 396           2   0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
   randomPrices          Main                                                 395           2   9.4    0.1     9.4    0.1
   randomSides           Main                                                 394           1   0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 CAF:main14              Main                                                 383           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  randomPrices           Main                                                 401           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl42_r2wH          Main                                                 382           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                   Main                                                 418           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:empty_rqz           Main                                                 381           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  empty                  Main                                                 403           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl40_r2wB          Main                                                 380           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  empty                  Main                                                 407           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl39_r2wz          Main                                                 379           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.1
  empty                  Main                                                 409           0   0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 CAF:lvl38_r2wv          Main                                                 378           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.1
  empty                  Main                                                 410           0   0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 CAF:maximumPrice        Main                                                 377           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  maximumPrice           Main                                                 402           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl14_r2vF          Main                                                 350           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  executeForPrice        Main                                                 414           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl12_r2vB          Main                                                 349           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  processOrder           Main                                                 415           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl10_r2vx          Main                                                 348           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  processOrder           Main                                                 416           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl8_r2vt           Main                                                 347           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  processOrder           Main                                                 399           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl6_r2vp           Main                                                 346           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  empty                  Main                                                 408           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl4_r2vl           Main                                                 345           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  empty                  Main                                                 411           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl2_r2vh           Main                                                 344           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  empty                  Main                                                 404           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Float                                            319           8   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Int                                              304           2   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.Handle.FD                                     278           2   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv                                239           2   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Conc.Signal                                      232           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     System.Random                                        222           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     Data.Fixed                                           217           3   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     Data.Time.Clock.POSIX                                214           2   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

I'm a newbie in Haskell. How do I interpret these reports, what do they mean and what can I do to make my code faster?

Comment: The first thing to consider would be your data structure for `pricePoints`.  I'm not certain how pure `Array` works, but I guess that updating elements forces a recopy of the array each time.  Try replacing it with a `Data.Map` in the first instance and see if you get a massive speed-up.

Comment: Thanks! Using Data.Map resulted in around 10% improvement. Not massive but helps! `time ./main                      
"Average execution price: 15480.460594795539, 2690.0 executions"
./main  9.24s user 0.05s system 96% cpu 9.585 total`

Comment: I'm suprised it was so small.  Can you paste the profile report for the `Data.Map` version?  Maybe on lpaste.org to avoid cluttering your question.

Comment: Also, try `Data.Map.Strict` too.

Comment: Also `Data.Sequence.Seq` instead of your lists.  You're doing too much appending at the end for a list to be sensible.  I would also try making your pair of `OrderBook` and `Event`s strict, and using `Data.List.foldl'` instead of `foldr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things we can note from the profiling you've made. There seems to be a lot of arrays in memory and also a fair amount of tuples, or rather tuple projections functions. So those seems to be good targets for optimization.

I first tried replacing arrays with `Data.Map` and for me that cut execution time in half. This is a much bigger win than you reported in one of the comments to your question. You didn't say exactly how you used maps but one thing I did was make sure that the initial map is empty, i.e. I didn't initialize it with lots of empty price points. In order for this to work, I used `findWithDefault` in `Data.Map` and let it return an empty list whenever the key wasn't available. If you didn't do that, then that might be the reason I got a much better speedup than you.

I went on to investigate the tuple selection functions. One common trick when writing high performance Haskell is to make sure that things are properly unboxed. Returning tuples from functions can be costly and you do that for the two of the most called functions, `executePrice` and `processOrder`. Before rewriting the code I looked at GHC's intermediate code to see if GHC had managed to unbox the tuples by itself. See this post for information on how to look at GHC intermediate representation: [Reading GHC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core). The thing to look for is whether the functions has return type `(OrderBook a, [Event a])` or `(# OrderBook a, [Event a] #)`. The latter is good, the former is bad.

What I found was that GHC had *not* been able to unbox the tuples and so I started by unboxing the return type of `processOrder` by hand. In order to do so I had to replace the `foldr` in `main` with a specialized loop, since `foldr` cannot deal with unboxed tuples. That gave a modest gain. Then I tried to unbox `executeForPrice` but that resulted in the following bug: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8762. There might be a way to avoid that bug but I didn't pursue it further.

Another small improvement: unbox all the fields you can in the types `OrderBook` and `Order`. It gave me a small gain.

I hope this helps. Good luck with optimizing your Haskell programs.

Comment: Using findWithDefault with Map has reduced running time by 60%, so that was really good. I'm going to try unboxing types next.

Here is the output with findWithDefault.
"Average execution price: 18870.52590673575, 2702.0 executions"
./OrderBook  0.96s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.978 total
(Compared with 4 seconds; I had bought a new computer which was also why it took me this long to reply; Had to get everything working again.)

Comment: Good to hear you're making progress. Note that the GHC developers have fixed the bug I filed so you should be able to make full use on unboxed tuples.