# Lazy ByteString : memory exploding in certain cases

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Below we have two seemingly functionally equivalent programs. For the first the memory remains constant, whereas for the second the memory explodes (using ghc 7.8.2 & bytestring-0.10.4.0 in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit):

**Non-exploding :**

```
--NoExplode.hs
--ghc -O3 NoExplode.hs
module Main where
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BLC

num = 1000000000
bytenull = BLC.pack ""

countDataPoint arg sum
  | arg == bytenull = sum
  | otherwise = countDataPoint (BL.tail arg) (sum+1)

test1 = BL.last $ BL.take num $ BLC.cycle $ BLC.pack "abc" 
test2 = countDataPoint (BL.take num $ BLC.cycle $ BLC.pack "abc") 0

main = do
  print test1
  print test2
```

**Exploding :**

```
--Explode.hs
--ghc -O3 Explode.hs
module Main where
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BLC

num = 1000000000
bytenull = BLC.pack ""

countDataPoint arg sum
  | arg == bytenull = sum
  | otherwise = countDataPoint (BL.tail arg) (sum+1)

longByteStr = BL.take num $ BLC.cycle $ BLC.pack "abc" 

test1 = BL.last $ longByteStr
test2 = countDataPoint (BL.take num $ BLC.cycle $ BLC.pack "abc") 0

main = do
  print test1
  print test2
```

**Additional details :**

The difference is that in`Explode.hs` I have taken `BL.take num $ BLC.cycle $ BLC.pack "abc"` out of the definition of `test1`, and assigned it to its own value `longByteStr`.

Strangely if we comment out either `print test1` or `print test2` in `Explode.hs` (but obviously not both), then the program does not explode.

***Is there a reason memory is exploding in `Explode.hs` and not in `NoExplode.hs`, and also why the exploding program (`Explode.hs`) requires both `print test1` and `print test2` in order to exlode?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why `ghc` performs common expression elimination in one case, but not in the other? Who knows. Maybe common expressions where killed by inlining. Basically it depends on internal implementation.

Regarding `-ddump-simp`, see this SO question: [Reading GHC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core)

---

I reproduced it with `ghc-7.8.2`. It performs common expression elimination. You can check output of `-ddump-simpl`. So you actually creating one lazy bytestring.

---

In the first version you create two lazy bytestrings. `print test1` forces the first one, but it is garbage collected on the fly because nobody else uses it. The same for `print test2` -- it forces the second bytestring, and it is GC'ed on the fly.

In the second version you create one lazy bytestring. `print test1` forces it, but it can't be GC'ed because it is needed for `print test2`. As a result, after the first `print` you have entire bytestring loaded into memory.

If you remove one `print`, the bytestring is GC'ed on the fly again. because it is not used anywhere else.

PS. "GC'ed on the fly" means: `print` takes the first chunk and outputs it to `stdout`. The chunk becomes available for GC. Then `prints` takes the second chunk, etc...

Comment: "In the second version you create one lazy bytestring. `print test1` forces it, but it can't be GC'ed because it is needed for `print test2`" : I am not sure I fully understand this. `longByteStr` is only used for `test1` and not `test2`

Comment: @artella Hmm.. yes, I missed that, sorry. But I can't reproduce it with `ghc-7.6`. What compiler version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using `ghc-7.8.2` on Ubuntu 64-bit and I have tested is quite a few times and can consistently reproduce it.

Comment: I was using `7.6.3`, and I reproduced it with `7.8.2`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ah that's cunning. I was unaware of this optimization. I have indirectly verified this by changing `"abc"` to `"def"` in the expression for `test2` in `Explode.hs`, and in this case the program no longer explodes! Thanks