# How to tell if strictness is actually inferred by GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am a haskell beginner, and I recently read about strictness analysis on [the haskell wiki](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness#Strictness_analysis). [GHC user's guide](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/options-optimise.html) reads:

> The strictness analyser figures out when arguments and variables in a function can be treated 'strictly' (that is they are always evaluated in the function at some point).

I've also read about when strictness can be inferred, in general. However, as a beginner, I am not always sure if ghc actually treats my piece of code, which I *intended* to be strict, as being strict.

Currently, I have no other way to find out whether the strict analysis is taking place than feeding the program with large data.

Is there any way to ask ghc if can infer a given code to be strict?

Comment: If you have an example of an expression you're interested in, post it and we can show you how to strictify it.

Comment: @user5402 Thank you for the kindness. The problem here is not about any specific code, but I'll post a question here when I do come upon one. It's great to know someone's got my back and where to seek for help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I've seen actually verify that GHC has inferred strictness is to read an intermediate representation of the compiled program called Core.

Some resources on learning to read Core output:

- [Reading GHC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core)
- http://www.scs.stanford.edu/11au-cs240h/notes/ghc-slides.html#(1)

However, another approach is to simply tell GHC which expressions should be evaluated strictly, for example, by using the `BangPatterns` language extension or the `seq` function.