# Why does a strict length function perform noticeably faster?

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I toyed around with definitions to better understand the evaluation model, and wrote two for the length of a list.

The naive definition:

```
len :: [a] -> Int
len [] = 0
len (_:xs) = 1 + len xs
```

The strict (and tail-recursive) definition:

```
slen :: [a] -> Int -> Int
slen [] n = n
slen (_:xs) !n = slen xs (n+1)
```

`len [1..10000000]` takes about 5-6 seconds to perform.
`slen [1..10000000] 0` takes about 3-4 seconds to perform.

I'm curious why. Before I checked the performances I was positive that they would perform about the same because `len` should have only one more thunk to evaluate at most. For demonstration purposes:

```
len [a,b,c,d]
= 1 + len [b,c,d]
= 1 + 1 + len [c,d]
= 1 + 1 + 1 + len [d]
= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + len []
= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
= 4
```

And

```
slen [a,b,c,d] 0
= slen [b,c,d] 1
= slen [c,d]   2
= slen [d]     3
= slen []      4
= 4
```

What makes `slen` noticeably faster?

P.S. I also wrote a tail-recursive lazy function (just like `slen` but lazy) as an attempt to close-in on the reason -- maybe it's because it was tail-recursive -- but it performed about the same as the naive definition.

Comment: The final step of `len` is not O(1). It is O(n) to add together n numbers. `slen` also uses O(n) memory while `len` uses O(1) memory.

Comment: @DavidYoung Oh I see! You're welcomed to write it as an answer. Could you also explain the memory consumption? (or just reference to where I can understand it further). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I got that backwards. `len` uses O(n) memory and `slen` uses O(1) memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The final step of `len` is not O(1). It is O(n) to add together n numbers. `len` also uses O(n) memory while `slen` uses O(1) memory.

The reason it uses O(n) memory is that each thunk uses up some memory. So when you have something like this:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + len []
```

there are five unevaluated thunks (including `len []`)

In GHCi, we can examine this thunk behavior a little easier with the `:sprint` command. The `:sprint` command prints the given value without forcing the evaluating of any thunks (you can learn more from `:help`). I'll use conses (`(:)`) since we can more easily evaluate each thunk one at a time, but the principle is the same.

```
λ> let ys = map id $ 1 : 2 : 3 : [] :: [Int] -- map id prevents GHCi from being too eager here
λ> :sprint ys
ys = _
λ> take 1 ys
[1]
λ> :sprint ys
ys = 1 : _
λ> take 2 ys
[1,2]
λ> :sprint ys
ys = 1 : 2 : _
λ> take 3 ys
[1,2,3]
λ> :sprint ys
ys = 1 : 2 : 3 : _
λ> take 4 ys
[1,2,3]
λ> :sprint ys
ys = [1,2,3]
```

Unevaluated thunks are represented by `_` and you can see that in the original `ys` there are `4` thunks nested inside of each other, one for each part of the list (including `[]`).

There isn't a good way that I know of to see this in `Int` because its evaluation is more all or nothing, but it still builds up a nested thunk in the same way. If you could see it like this, its evaluation would look something like this:

```
len [a,b,c,d]
= 1 + len [b,c,d]
= 1 + 1 + len [c,d]
= 1 + 1 + 1 + len [d]
= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + len []
= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1       -- Here it stops building the thunks and starts evaluating them
= 1 + 1 + 2
= 1 + 3
= 4
```

Answer (score 4):

David Young's answer gives the correct explanation of the difference in evaluation order. You should think about Haskell evaluation in the way he outlines.

Let me show you how you can see the difference in the Core. I think it's actually more visible with optimizations on, because the evaluation ends up as an explicit `case` statement. If you've never played with Core before, see the canonical SO question on the topic: [Reading GHC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core).

Generate the core output with `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -ddump-to-file SO27392665.hs`. You'll see that GHC splits both `len` and `slen` into a recursive "worker" function, `$wlen` or `$wslen`, and a nonrecursive "wrapper" function. Because the vast majority of the time is spent in the recursive "workers," focus on them:

```
Rec {
$wlen
$wlen =
  \ @ a_arZ w_sOR ->
    case w_sOR of _ {
      [] -> 0;
      : ds_dNU xs_as0 ->
        case $wlen xs_as0 of ww_sOU { __DEFAULT -> +# 1 ww_sOU }
    }
end Rec }

len
len =
  \ @ a_arZ w_sOR ->
    case $wlen w_sOR of ww_sOU { __DEFAULT -> I# ww_sOU }

Rec {
$wslen
$wslen =
  \ @ a_arR w_sOW ww_sP0 ->
    case w_sOW of _ {
      [] -> ww_sP0;
      : ds_dNS xs_asW -> $wslen xs_asW (+# ww_sP0 1)
    }
end Rec }

slen
slen =
  \ @ a_arR w_sOW w1_sOX ->
    case w1_sOX of _ { I# ww1_sP0 ->
    case $wslen w_sOW ww1_sP0 of ww2_sP4 { __DEFAULT -> I# ww2_sP4 }
    }
```

You can see that `$wslen` has only one `case`, while `$wlen` has two. If you go look at David's answer, you can trace what happens in `$wlen`: it does its case analysis on the outermost list constructor (`[]`/`:`), then makes the recursive call to `$wlen xs_as0` (i.e. `len xs`), which it also `case`s, i.e. forces the accumulated thunk.

In `$wslen`, on the other hand, there's only the one `case` statement. In the recursive branch, there's simply an unboxed addition, `(+# ww_sP0 1)`, which doesn't create a thunk.

(Note: a previous version of this answer had stated that with `-O` GHC could specialize `$wslen` but not `$wlen` to use unboxed `Int#`s. That's not the case.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, first and foremost :). The naive definition is slower even without any optimizations (GHCi). Would GHC still unbox the Int like that?

Comment: No, without optimizations GHC doesn't eliminate the boxing and unboxing. Try generating the Core; you can see that `slen` unboxes the accumulator each time. In the unoptimized case, I think it's simply that it evaluates the thunks immediately rather than building them up.