# Compare generated code in ghc

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

A common practice in the C world to compare two fragmets of C is to see what assembly they generate. I wanted to know what code GHC would generate in the case of:

```
afmap :: Functor f => (a -> b -> c) -> f b -> a -> f c
afmap fn fb a' = (fn a') <$> fb
```

and

```
afmap  = flip . (((.).(.)) fmap ($))
```

So I tried:

```
$ ghc -S test.hs -o test.S
```

Which (unsurprisingly) yielded more or less unreadable code.

What is the correct way (if any) to evaluate how ghc optimizes code?

Comment: I would look at the produced core. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core)

Comment: Interesting answers. For the record, probably the answer to my question is to be found in [ghc-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core).

Comment: That's a great tool

Comment: That's a great tool that only works on Unix.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, Its code is fairly concise and the meat of actually calling ghc is [about 20 loc](https://github.com/shachaf/ghc-core/blob/master/ghc-core.hs#L172L189) so I guess you are not really missing out too much.

Comment: And ghc by itself emits core. This just tidies it up a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assembly is probably a bit too low-level. You probably want to look at Core, GHC's intermediate optimisation language.

Essentially, GHC translates Haskell to Core, does a wide variety of optimisation passes on it, and eventually transforms Core to STG and then on to C-- and the native code generator (i.e., assembly) or via LLVM (I don't know much about that particular pathway).

In particular, Core is still reasonably high-level, and somewhat similar to Haskell (i.e., it has similar abstractions like pattern-matching and lazy evaluation). If two programs produce the same Core, then obviously they produce the same machine code.

Comment: That is correct and helpful. A side note for future reference: one needs to add the line `module Test (afmap) where`  at the top of the input file to have `ghc` actually compile the function.