# What does Core Haskell applying types to functions mean?

Tags: function, haskell, types, ghc, lambda-calculus

I wrote a custom pretty printer for Core Haskell in order to better study Core's structure. The gist of this pretty printer is that it takes a [CoreModule](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#t:CoreModule) and includes data constructors in the output, which the default `Outputable` implementation does not seem to do.

Here is the code of the module that I am running the pretty printer on:

```
module Bar2 where

add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add a b = a + b

add2 a b = a + b
```

Here is the pretty printer output:

```
------------------------------- Module Metadata --------------------------------
Module { "main" :: modulePackageId, "Bar2" :: moduleName }
-------------------------------- Type Bindings ---------------------------------
[r0 :-> Identifier ‘add’, rjH :-> Identifier ‘add2’]
-------------------------------- Core Bindings ---------------------------------
NonRec (Id "add2")
       (Lam (TyVar "a")
            (Lam (Id "$dNum")
                 (Lam (Id "a1")
                      (Lam (Id "b")
                           (App (App (App (App (Var (Id "+"))
                                               (Type (TyVar (TyVar "a"))))
                                          (Var (Id "$dNum")))
                                     (Var (Id "a1")))
                                (Var (Id "b")))))))

NonRec (Id "add")
       (Lam (Id "a")
            (Lam (Id "b")
                 (App (App (App (App (Var (Id "+"))
                                     (Type (TyConApp (Int) [])))
                                (Var (Id "$fNumInt")))
                           (Var (Id "a")))
                      (Var (Id "b")))))
--------------------------------- Safe Haskell ---------------------------------
Safe
------------------------------------- End --------------------------------------
```

What is confusing to me is that in both instances, Core appears to be applying a type variable, or a type constructor to the `+` function, as well as some `$dNum` or `$fNumInt` before taking in the arguments.

For the `add` function, the type is also explicitly given, while the `add2` is left up to compiler inference. This also seems to affect the number of arguments that the chain of lambda functions requires for evaluation, with `add` needing 2 while `add2` requiring 4.

What does this all mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Core is pretty much [SystemF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) (technically [SystemFC](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ext-f/fc-tldi.pdf)). In SystemF, type variables also need to be arguments to the function. In your example, Haskell infers that

```
add2 :: Num a => a -> a -> a 
add2 a b = a + b
```

That explains the `TyVar "a"` argument to `add2`.

Also, Haskell has to find a way to dispatch to the 'right' set of `Num` functions depending on what the type of the arguments `a` and `b` is. It does that by having a dictionary argument for each type class constraint. That's the `Id $dNum` argument. In the case of `add`, Haskell already knows which dictionary the appropriate `(+)` function can be found since it knows it knows the operation is on `Int` (so it doesn't need to be passed in: it's just `$fNumInt`).

Essentially what happens under the hood is that for each typeclass Haskell makes a record `data $d<Class> = ...` with fields that are the functions inside the typeclass. Then, for each instance, it makes another `$f<Class><Type> :: $d<Class>`. [This is explained in more detail here](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150PLD/Notes/TypeClasses.pdf)

[Here is another excellent answer describing Core related things.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core)

Answer (score 5):

In GHC 8.x you can play with type arguments in Haskell as well, similarly to Core. Here's an example with some more annotations, based on the posted code.

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add a b = (+) @ Int a b
```

The `(+) @ Int` specializes the polymorphic `(+)` operator so that it works on type `Int`.

In Core, you also see the typeclass dictionary being passed around `$fNumInt`.

```
add2 :: forall n. Num n => n -> n -> n    
add2 a b = (+) @ n a b
```

This is basically the same, except that `n` is not known.

In Core, `add2` takes a hidden "type-valued" argument `n` (confusingly called `a` in the posted example, i.e. `(Lam (TyVar "a") ...`), which is then forwarded to `(+)` as a type argument. Since the dictionary is now unknown, in Core there is another hidden argument: the dictionary has to be passed by the caller of `add2`, which then forwards it to `(+)`. This additional argument is called `$dNum` (See `(Lam (Id "$dNum") ...`).