# Does Haskell/Frege ever recalcuate elements of a lazy list?

Tags: haskell, caching, lazy-evaluation, frege

Suppose I have a list of all primes, defined as

```
primes :: (Enum α, Integral α) => [α]
primes = sieve [2..]
  where sieve :: (Integral α) => [α] -> [α]
        sieve []     = undefined
        sieve (x:xs) = x : (sieve $ filter ((/= 0) . (flip mod x)) xs)
```

and I want to feed `primes` through multiple, different functions like:

```
sumOfPrimesLessThan :: (Integral α) => α -> α
sumOfPrimesLessThan n = sum $ takeWhile (< n) primes
```

or

```
productOfPrimesLessThan :: (Integral α) => α -> α
productOfPrimesLessThan n = foldl (*) 1 $ takeWhile (< n) primes
```

or something, as if by doing

```
main = do print (sumOfPrimesLessThan     1000 :: Integer)
          print (productOfPrimesLessThan 1000 :: Integer)
```

Would Haskell, at any point in time, recalculate `primes`, or any part thereof? What would cached? What wouldn't be cached?

**Addendum 0:** Suppose I had another function

```
prime = flip elem primes
```

If `prime` were to be evaluated with different arguments, would each evaluation re-evaluate `primes`? For example:

```
allPrime = all prime
```

Comment: The question is indeed interesting when `primes` is polymorphic. On the other hand, if you had `primes :: [Int]`, then `primes` would only be calculated once.

Comment: For Frege, Alec's brilliant answer applies accordingly. A polymorphic value is actually a function that takes instances (i.e. records of functions) which it uses to fulfill its tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case (for Haskell GHC) the answer is that `primes` is recalculated. Yet, if you had a monomorphic signature like `primes :: [Int]`, that wouldn't be the case. Here's a way to debug this: import `Debug.Trace` and add the `trace` function to `primes`

```
primes :: (Enum α, Integral α) => [α]
primes = trace "call to primes" $ sieve [2..]
  where sieve :: (Integral α) => [α] -> [α]
        sieve []     = undefined
        sieve (x:xs) = x : (sieve $ filter ((/= 0) . (flip mod x)) xs)
```

Now, every time `primes` is called, you will see "call to primes" printed out. Compiling your program (with or without optimizations), I get two calls to `primes`.

#### But why?

Haskell actually compiles your version of `primes` to a function that takes one type argument, and so the use of `primes` inside `sumOfPrimesLessThan` and `productOfPrimesLessThan` is actually a function call (and function calls are not in general memoized in Haskell, for pretty obvious reasons). When you call `sumOfPrimesLessThan 1000 :: Integer`, for example, you actually give it two arguments: the value `1000` and the type argument `Integer`. `sumOfPrimesLessThan` then passes this second argument on to primes.

On the other hand, if you had type signatures that were monomorphic, like `primes :: [Int]`, `sumOfPrimesLessThan :: Int -> Int`, and `productOfPrimesLessThan :: Int -> Int`, Haskell compiles `primes` down to just a regular thunk value, so it only gets evaluated once.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248771/what-does-core-haskell-applying-types-to-functions-mean/38249762#38249762) is another explanation of how Haskell represents values and functions on the inside I gave not long ago.

#### `SPECIALIZE` pragma (specific to GHC)

Sometimes you would like to be able to tell GHC that even if your expression is polymorphic, you'd like it to be treated as monomorphic for a couple types. (So you kind of wish you had a second version `primes :: [Integer]` even if in general `primes :: (Enum α, Integral α) => [α]`.) You can specify this using the `SPECIALIZE` pragma:

```
{-# SPECIALIZE primes :: [Integer] #-}
primes :: (Enum a,Integral a) => [a]
primes = ...
```

And now, just for the `Integer` type, `primes` will only be computed once. For other types (like `Int`), we will still get the same behavior as before.

#### In response to addendums

For multiple calls to `prime = flip elem primes` where `prime` is monomorphic ("instantiated"), you would still have only one call to `primes`. Once `primes` is monomorphic, it can be shared everywhere. Also, beware the monomorphism restriction in your `allPrime = all prime` example - you'll need to specify which instance of `Foldable` want (`allPrime = all prime` is subtly different from `allPrime xs = all prime xs`).

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, I think the first two sentences of your answer might be inverted (that is, I think the first sentence should end with “yes” but the second should end with “no”). Nice answer, though. :)

Comment: @AlexisKing He is co-answering the question.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that monomorphic CAFs may be shared while polymorphic CAFs cannot, for the reasons you mention. Also, be aware that the monomorphism restriction will turn some seemingly polymorphic CAFs into monomorphic ones, e.g., `primes` without an explicit annotation.

Comment: If the functions above had remained polymorphic, would a simple `where` clause (or just anywhere in the current module) defining monomorphic versions of the functions suffice? e.g. `main = ... where integerPrimes = primes :: [Integer]`?

Comment: @AliciaRose Yes, provided you then used `integerPrimes` everywhere. Also, would you mind changing the signatures in the question back to their polymorphic forms? It's a great question and other people won't be able to understand what is going on now that the signatures are all different.

Comment: @Alec - Does use of the SPECIALIZE pragma have an effect here?

Comment: @ErikR Yep it does (when compiling with `-O2`).

Comment: @Alec so if `primes` were to remain polymorphic, would monomorphic functions that use `primes` (or monomorphic functions that use functions that use `primes`, and so on) be thunked, and `primes` would only be evaluated once for said thunk?

Comment: @AliciaRose No, but if you do something like `let primesInt = primes in ...` where the context of the use implies `primesInt :: [Int]` then `primesInt` will be only evaluated once.

Comment: @Alec Suppose I have a function `a` that calls a function `b` that calls ... that calls `primes`. Could I still do `let aInts = a in ...` or something, where `aInts` is implied to be `[Int]` or something like in your example, where `primes` is still evaluated only once? I ask this because I'm still a little unsure how "deep" Haskell will go before it stops thunking.