# Is following Fibonacci function O(n) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, big-o, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci

As I learnt in SICP, tree recursion's complexity grows exponentially with n. If in Haskell I wrote like,

```
fib n | n <= 1 = n
      | otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Is it true that, since Haskell is lazy, it calculate `fib 1`, `fib 2`... all once, so the complexity is linear with n?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memoization in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208258/memoization-in-haskell)

Comment: No, Haskell does not memoize functions. See something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466284/how-is-this-fibonacci-function-memoized). Note that further complications for memoization also arise from polymorphic code ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879778/does-haskell-frege-ever-recalcuate-elements-of-a-lazy-list/38880106#38880106) question is sort of relevant)

Comment: If you want that *function*, you should use exponentiation of matrices by squaring. That's considerably faster than linear time would be, even if you'd achieved it.

Comment: @dfeuer Technically that's still O(n). Sure, doing O(log n) multiplications + additions has probably smaller constants than the naive solution with n additions, but both do O(n) bit operations.

Comment: @dfeuer You mean the Exercise 1.19 of SICP

Comment: @Bakuriu, by that standard, the list approach isn't even linear, is it?

Comment: @Bakuriu, also, does your statement continue to hold if one uses extremely fancy multiplication algorithms (e.g., Fourier transform ones)?

Comment: I don't have SICP in front of me, Xiaojun Chen, so I don't know.

Comment: @dfeuer The number of bits in fibonacci numbers is O(n) (they grow exponentially), that's pretty definitive regarding the lower bound complexity to compute them, that was my point.

Comment: @Bakuriu, right, I forgot just how fast they go. Are you sure the naive approach of doing `n` additions is O(n)?

Answer (score 4):

`Debug.Trace` can give the number of times `fib` is called :

```
import Debug.Trace

fib :: Int -> Int
fib n = trace "CALL" $ case n of
  0 -> 0
  1 -> 1
  _ -> fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

For `fib 5`, it prints CALL 15 times, so it's not O(n).