# How to define generic function without argument of generic type?

Tags: haskell, generics

I'm reading "Haskell Book"'s monoid section right now where author uses QuickCheck to check monoid laws. After writing some things on my own, I have this code:

```
module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Test.QuickCheck

monoidAssoc :: (Eq m, Monoid m) => m -> m -> m -> Bool
monoidAssoc a b c = ((a <> b) <> c) == (a <> (b <> c))

monoidLeftId :: (Eq m, Monoid m) => m -> Bool
monoidLeftId a = (mempty <> a) == a

monoidRightId :: (Eq m, Monoid m) => m -> Bool
monoidRightId a = (a <> mempty) == a

type AssocCheck a = a -> a -> a -> Bool
type IdCheck a = a -> Bool

main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickCheck (monoidAssoc   :: AssocCheck (Maybe String))
  quickCheck (monoidLeftId  :: IdCheck (Maybe String))
  quickCheck (monoidRightId :: IdCheck (Maybe String))

  quickCheck (monoidAssoc   :: AssocCheck [String])
  quickCheck (monoidLeftId  :: IdCheck [String])
  quickCheck (monoidRightId :: IdCheck [String])
```

As you can see `main` function has two almost same blocks which I would like to reduce to something like this:

```
checkMonoid :: (Eq m, Monoid m) => m -> IO ()
checkMonoid = do
  quickCheck (monoidAssoc   :: AssocCheck m)
  quickCheck (monoidLeftId  :: IdCheck m)
  quickCheck (monoidRightId :: IdCheck m)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  checkMonoid :: Maybe String -> IO ()
  checkMonoid :: [String] -> IO ()
```

But this obviously will not work. What I want here is to somehow pass type to the `checkMonoid` function so `quickCheck` function will know what `arbitrary` data must be generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of thing `TypeApplication` lets you do - you can explicitly pass the type for `m`. You then also need `ScopedTypeVariables` to make sure that all the `m`s inside you `checkMonoid` are the same, and `AllowAmbiguousTypes` to let GHC know that you are fine with the fact that `checkMonoid` will be ambiguous without a type application.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

-- ...

checkMonoid :: forall m. (Eq m, Monoid m, Show m, Arbitrary m) => IO ()
checkMonoid = do
  quickCheck (monoidAssoc   :: AssocCheck m)
  quickCheck (monoidLeftId  :: IdCheck m)
  quickCheck (monoidRightId :: IdCheck m)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  checkMonoid @(Maybe String)
  checkMonoid @[String]
```

The principal behind `TypeApplications` is that under the hood Haskell is transforming polymorphic functions into functions that also take types as arguments ([see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38249762/3072788)) - and normally GHC takes care of figuring out which type arguments to fill in. With `TypeApplications`, `@SomeType` says "let the first type argument to the preceding function call be `SomeType`".

By having the `forall m.` I make sure GHC will do the above. Then, when I call `checkMonoid`, I pass the type for `m` explicitly.