# Haskell Performance by Example

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc

I have these basic types in my code:

```
newtype Foo (m :: Factored) = Foo Int64 deriving (NFData)

foo :: forall m . (Fact m) => Foo m -> Foo m

class T t where t :: (Fact m ) => t m -> t m

instance T Foo where t = foo

newtype Bar t (m :: Factored) = Bar (t m) deriving (NFData)

bar :: (Fact m, T t) => Bar t m -> Bar t m
bar (Bar v) = Bar $ t v
```

(ignore `Fact` and `Factored` for the moment). I'm benchmarking the code at different levels, comparing the performance of `foo`, `t`, and `bar`. In the benchmarks, `t = foo`, and `bar` just applies `t` through a `newtype`. Thus their runtime should be essentially identical, but [criterion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) reports that `foo` takes 9.2ns, `t` takes about twice that at 17.45ns, and `bar` takes a whopping 268.1ns.

I've experimented with adding `INLINABLE` and even a `SPECIALIZE` pragma, but they aren't helping. I want to believe that GHC has some magic syntax/optimization/etc that can be *consistently* applied to solve these types of performance issues. For example, I've seen cases where writing code in point-free style has dramatic performance implications.

The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/crockeea/HaskellPerfTest). I promise it's not intimidating. The modules are:

- Foo: defines `Foo`, `foo`, and `T`
- Bar: defines `Bar` and `bar`
- FooBench: defines a benchmark for `foo`
- TBench: defines a benchmark for `t`
- BarBench: defines a benchmark for `bar`
- Main: runs the three benchmarks
- Factored: defines `Fact` and `Factored` using [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons)

Most of the modules are tiny; I defined the three benchmarks in separate files so that I could examine their core. I generated the core for the three `*Bench` modules and aligned them the best I could. They're only ~250 lines each, and the first ~200 lines are identical, up to renaming. The problem is that I don't know what to make of the last 50 or so lines. The (core) diff for `FooBench` vs `TBench` is [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/zmemsr6n), the diff for `TBench` vs `BarBench` is [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/lelh4hfj), and the diff for `FooBench` vs `BarBench` is [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/hzrziczu).

Just a few of the questions I have:

1. At a high level, what is the essential difference between the core files? I'm looking for something like "*Here* you can see that GHC isn't inlining the call to `x`." What should I be looking for?
2. What can be done to make the three benchmarks all run in about 9.2ns? GHC optimizations? `INLINE`/`INLINABLE` pragmas? `SPECIALIZE` pragmas that I missed? (You aren't allowed to specialized for `F128::Factored`; in my real library this value may be reified at runtime.) Restricting/delaying inlining to a particular phase?

Although I'm looking for an actual solution to make the benchmarks all fast, it's possible that tricks that work for this example won't scale to my real library. As a result, I'm also looking for the "high-level" explanation of why a particular technique should work.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core

Comment: My _guess_ is that the difference you're observing is the cost of passing the `Fact` and `T` dictionaries around

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'd really like to get specialization all the way down the stack so that there aren't any dictionaries involved once you monomorphize at the top level. Any idea how to make that happen?

Comment: @Michael How do you suggest I benchmark code? Every question I've seen on SO involving people *not* using criterion ends up with everyone talking about how it's the only way to get reliable data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, looking at `bar`:

```
bar :: (Fact m, T t) => Bar t m -> Bar t m
bar (Bar v) = Bar $ t v
```

we can write this without needing the argument using `coerce`:

```
bar :: (Fact m, T t) => Bar t m -> Bar t m
bar = (coerce :: (t m -> t m) -> Bar t m -> Bar t m) t
```

this (as we'd hope) gets `bar` performing the same as `t`. (In fact the core for `TBench` and `BarBench` is exactly the same, excluding type signatures).

I'm not entirely sure why, but using `INLINE` instead of `INLINEABLE` makes `t` and `bar` perform the same as `foo`. I'm not an expert but it's normally better to use `INLINE` for small functions that you're sure you want to inline.

That said I think some of these issues are from how criterion does benchmarks to stop `ghc` cheating. For instance, writing `bench "Bar" $ nf (GHC.Magic.inline bar) x` on your original code has `bar` performing the same as `foo`. I suspect a "real" program wouldn't be so delicate.

Comment: How is `bar` not violating the [newtypes are free](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/NewtypeWrappers) model? I changed my GADTs to newtypes for the example precisely so that I could rule out data constructors being the issue. Since I don't have newtypes in my real code, I can't use `coerce`.

Comment: As for `INLINE`/`INLINABLE`, neither seem to help in my real code. It's very difficult to make an example small enough to get input on, but large enough that solutions still apply. Similarly with `GHC.Magic.inline` (which sounds great!), I only managed to slow my program down. I really do appreciate your effort though, and I'll continue to play around with the ideas.

Comment: I'm also interested if you looked at the core for a diagnosis, or if you only looked at it as a confirmation of the solution. I really just want to understand how you approached the problem.

Comment: Honestly I just tried out different things. I tried `GHC.Magic.inline` first so I knew it was in inlining problem. I did try to look at the core but I only understand the basics. I think by writing `bar (Bar v) = Bar $ t v` you change `bar`s airity so `bar` won't willingly inline unless it's directly applied to a `Bar` (which it isn't in the benchmark).