# How to dump the result of loop fusion in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Section 2.3.1.1 "A note on fusion" of [Haskell Wiki's Numeric Haskell page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Vector_Tutorial) explains loop fusion by showing the optimised code as in the following:

Before optimization:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

test :: V.Vector Int -> Double
test = V.foldl (\ a b -> a * sqrt (fromIntegral b)) 0

create :: Int -> V.Vector Int
create n = (V.enumFromTo 1 n)

main = print (test (create 1000000))
```

After optimization:

```
main_$s$wfoldlM_loop :: Int# -> Double# -> Double#
main_$s$wfoldlM_loop =
  \ (sc_sWA :: Int#) (sc1_sWB :: Double#) ->
    case <=# sc_sWA 1000000 of _ {
      False -> sc1_sWB;
      True ->
        main_$s$wfoldlM_loop
          (+# sc_sWA 1)
          (*##
             sc1_sWB (sqrtDouble# (int2Double# sc_sWA)))
    }
```

I am curious about how I can see the optimised code like this. The article mentioned *ghc-core tool*, but didn't show the specific command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you want to look at GHC Core. The primary option to see core output is to use the `-ddump-simpl` for GHC, described [here](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/debugging.html#ghc-flag--ddump-simpl). There are also many flags to modify that output (to make it simpler), such as `-dsuppress-all`.

Information on actually *reading* core can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core).